# Is there a way to adjust decimal points on weight in magento?

Tags: magento, decimal

The default decimal points are 4 digits "1.0000" is there a way i can adjust it on front end that would only show 2 decimal points? like: "1.00"

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use php function for that

```
<?php echo number_format($weight,2); ?>
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the help -- but where do i add this in? sorry for being a noob, i just started using magento today :D

P.S. I cant find the attributes.phtml under app/design/frontend/YOUR THEME/template/catalog/product/view/

as discussed on the internet

Comment: you can find attributes.phtml file in this location app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml 
rather than change in base file I will recommend to you  copy and paste this file and put in your theme folder app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
then you change in this file.

Comment: woah! thanks mate! its all good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In database, weight attribute have backend_type set to decimal.

To change the decimal precision of attributes that have a backend_type set to decimal,

You have to change the type of value in this table :

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

If you have not change yet, you should see :

```
decimal(12,4)
```

In your case, you have to replace with

```
decimal(12,2)
```